# free field extensions vs linearly disjoint field extensions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be subfields of an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ and $E$ a common subfield of both $K_1$ and $K_2$. We say that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are **linearly disjoint** over $E$ if every tuple $\bar{a}$ in $K_1$ that is linearly independent over $E$, remains linearly independent over $K_2$. Similarly, we say that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are **free** over $E$ if every tuple $\bar{a}$ in $K_1$ that is algebraically independent over $E$ remains algebraically independent over $E$.

In some lecture notes I am studying, they state that if $E$ is an algebraically closed field, then the two notions above agree, but no proof or reference is given. Why is this true?

Comment: Did you mean $E=K_1\cap K_2$? Otherwise try with $E=\Bbb{C},K_1=E(t^2), K_2=K_1(t)$ then $1,t$ are $K_1$ and $K_2$ algebraically dependent, $K_2$ linearly dependent, and $K_1$ linearly independent.